# Is it possible to create a CImageList with alpha blending transparency?

Tags: c++, image, mfc, alphablending, mfc-feature-pack

I would like to know if it is possible to create a `CImageList` with alpha blending transparency.

Sample code that creates a `CImageList` with ugly transparency (no alpha blending):

```cpp
CGdiPlusBitmapResource m_pBitmap;
m_pBitmap.Load(IDB_RIBBON_FILESMALL,_T("PNG"),AfxGetResourceHandle());
    
HBITMAP hBitmap;
m_pBitmap.m_pBitmap->GetHBITMAP(RGB(0,0,0),&hBitmap );

CImageList *pList=new CImageList;
CBitmap bm;
bm.Attach(hBitmap);
pList->Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 0, 4);
pList->Add(&bm, RGB(255,0,255));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the `ILC_MASK` flag (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761389(v=vs.85).aspx)):

> ### Using 32 Bit Anti-Aliased Icons
>
> Windows XP imagelists, which are
>   collections of images used with
>   certain controls such as list-view
>   controls, support the use of 32-bit
>   anti-aliased icons and bitmaps. Color
>   values use 24 bits, and 8 bits are
>   used as an alpha channel on the icons.
>   To create an imagelist that can handle
>   a 32-bits-per-pixel (bpp) image, call
>   the `ImageList_Create` function passing
>   in an `ILC_COLOR32` flag.

Comment: +1.  Not real clear from the post but the options are not compatible.  Either mask or use a 32bpp with alpha, not both.