# Are images in ILC_COLOR32 image lists alpha premultiplied or not? I'm getting conflicting information

Tags: winapi, imagelist, comctl32, premultiplied-alpha

Very simple question here: Are `ILC_COLOR32` Image Lists alpha-premultiplied or not? Various questions on Stack Overflow, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640823/is-it-possible-to-create-a-cimagelist-with-alpha-blending-transparency/2640897#2640897), imply they are; [this wxWidgets bug](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/9050#comment:1), however, indicates otherwise. [The only place where Microsoft actually says `ILC_COLOR32` is used for alpha-blended image list entries](https://web.archive.org/web/20100512144953/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997646.aspx#xptheming_topic13) doesn't say (and all `ILC_COLOR32`'s docs say about it is that it is a "32-bit DIB section", which, if I understand the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` docs correctly, technically does not contain alpha information; the top 8 bits of each color are ignored). Thanks!

Comment: The documentation for the [`BLENDFUNCTION` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183393(v=vs.85).aspx) says the alpha must be premultiplied, and it's part of the Bitmap documentation.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `ImageList_Draw` isn't documented as using `AlphaBlend` however (although odds are it does).

Comment: I don't see where that SO question you linked implies that they are pre-multiplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images that you supply to, and extract from, `ILC_COLOR32` image lists do not have pre-multiplied alpha channels.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've updated my code; I probably should find a public domain icon with actual alpha blending to test though :|

Comment: @andlabs You can test using the built-in Windows icons. They're not publicly distributable, but you licensed them for your machine, so you can use them for testing. :-) Look in `%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll` If you own Visual Studio, you can also use [these icons](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825), which used to be bundled with older versions, but are now available for download.

Comment: David, this was what I thought too, but I didn't post the answer because I didn't have an authoritative reference. Do you know if this is documented anywhere in MSDN or elsewhere? Or are you basing this just on experience?

Comment: @Cody the fact that the image list docs don't mention pre mult alpha is the best I know.